# How to SSH tunnel access from local macbook to remote Windows server

Tags: ssh

I am trying to access Remote Windows Server via bastion host by using SSH tunnel.

- SSH server (bastion host)

  - host: x.x.x.x
  - port: 8822
  - user: user1
  - auth: key pair
- Remote Windows server

  - host: y.y.y.y
  - port: 3389
  - user: user1
  - auth: password

We have key pair in local directory and the public key is registered to the bastion host.

- private key: ~/.ssh/bastion.p8
- public key: ~/.ssh/bastion.pub

I tried to create SSH tunnel to the bastion host by this command.

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/bastion.p8 -p 48882 y.y.y.y -L 3389:y.y.y.y:3389
```

Then try to connect Remote Windows server using Remote Desktop but it did not work.

> We couldn't connect to the remote PC. Make sure the PC is turned on and connected to the network, and that remote access is enabled.
> Error code: 0x204

Am I missing somehting?